# Why my setOnKeyListener() does not work?

Tags: java, android

My coworker's previous source code about the certain Alert Dialog is

```
        this.mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                SimLog.d(TAG, "onKeyDown()[back:4]=" + keyCode);
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    dismiss();
                    doCancelImport();
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        };
```

To set some modifications to this dialog, I had to change this code to:

```
        this.mProgressDialog = mBuilder.create();
        this.mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                SimLog.d(TAG, "onKeyDown()[back:4]=" + keyCode);
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    dismiss();
                    doCancelImport();
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onKey(keyCode, event);
            }
        });
```

But my eclipse shows an error:

"The method setOnKeyListener(DialogInterface.OnKeyListener) in the type Dialog is not applicable for the arguments(new OnKeyListener())"

Why this does not work? How can I modify this?

Comment: You've probably imported a different class that also happens to be called OnKeyListener.

Comment: Can you list your imports? Because I think there is 2 or more classes with that name that you can accidentally import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably imported the wrong `OnKeyListener` class, therefore the argument type of `setOnKeyListener()` does not match.

Either you use this instead:

```
this.mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
```

Or you import the correct type with `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;`

Comment: Your recommendation of using this.mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.onKeyListener() { works well. But this time, eclipse shows another red underlines in dismiss(); and return super.onKey(keyCode, event);

Comment: I fixed the first red underline with editing dismiss(); to ActivityName.this.mProgressDialog.dismiss(); but still stucked on fixing second problem.. it shows "The method onKey(int, keyEvent) is undefined for the type Object". how can I deal with this case?

Comment: You can call `dialog.dismiss()` instead and change `return super.onKey(keyCode, event);` to `return true`.

Comment: Then it'll be okay to just set "return false;" or "return true;" outside the "if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)" part?

Comment: I see, `return false` outside the if statement would be more appropriate.